# How to emit OnComplete and OnError events as observable item?

Tags: rx-java

I want to create `Observable` from `Completable` that emits Completable's `OnError` and `OnComplete` events.

Example of event:

```kotlin
    private sealed class Result {

        class Success : Result()

        class Error(val errorMessage: String) : Result()
    }
```

`OnError` event should be mapped to `Error`, `OnComplete` to `Success`

I understand how to emit `Error` if observable emits error event:

```kotlin
val completable = ...
completable.
    .toObservable<Result>()
    .onErrorReturn { error -> Result.Error(error.message.orEmpty()) }
```

But i can't find solution for emitting `OnComplete` event.
Is it possible it with using standard RxJava operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize [.materialize()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/materialize-dematerialize.html) function.

For example like this:

```
Completable.complete()
        .toObservable<Result>()
        .materialize()
        .map {
            when {
                it.isOnError -> 1
                it.isOnComplete -> 0 
                else -> 2 // not present in Completable
            }
        }
```